# How to rationalize a symbolic fraction in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, fractions

I have a symbolic expression in Matlab, whose numerator and denominator contain square roots of prime numbers. I would like to rationalize the denominator of the fraction. Any ideas ? I have tried to use the "simplify" function from the symbolic toolbox and it does work sometimes. But some other times it is returning the fraction as is.

For example:

[image] does not work with simplify, but

[image] works.

In other words,

`simplify((-sym(sqrt(3)) + 4 * sym(sqrt(5)))/(sym(sqrt(2)) - 4 * sqrt(5)))` gives the same expression as a result.

Whereas,
`simplify((sym(sqrt(2)) + 4 * sym(sqrt(3)))/(3*sym(sqrt(2)) - sqrt(3)))` returns the rationalized fraction shown in the picture.

Thank you,
Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, very helpful. I provided all the details and clearly stated that I tried simplify. I did try simplifyFraction but it did not do anything.

Comment: I recommend that you post MATLAB code that creates those fractions, rather than images of the fractions. That makes it easier to people to test and write an answer (and thus increases your likelihood of getting an answer). It also makes the question useful to those who cannot see and depend on screen readers to read your question. Thanks!

Comment: Probably a relevant tip from TMW: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html#btrwama-2